# How to create a virtual drive on windows in Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, subst

How to create a virtual drive on Windows in Rust? (Similar to what the subst command does on windows)
I don't seem to find such an API in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @solomon-ucko @caesar , I wrapped a tool library [win_subst](https://crates.io/crates/win_subst) based on [windows-rs](https://crates.io/crates/windows) for convenient use.

Answer (score 2):

The only seemingly relevant function I see being invoked from `subst.exe` is [`DefineDosDevice(dwFlags, lpDeviceName, lpTargetPath)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-definedosdevicew):

> Defines, redefines, or deletes MS-DOS device names.
>
> `[in] lpDeviceName`
> A pointer to an MS-DOS device name string specifying the device the function is defining, redefining, or deleting.
>
> `[in, optional] lpTargetPath`
> A pointer to a path string that will implement this device.

Use whichever [Rust binding](https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/fileapi/fn.DefineDosDeviceW.html) you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetVolumeMountPointW`:

- Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setvolumemountpointw

> **SetVolumeMountPointW function (winbase.h)**
>
> Associates a volume with a drive letter or a directory on another volume.

> **Parameters**
>
> `[in] lpszVolumeMountPoint`
>
> The user-mode path to be associated with the volume. This may be a drive letter (for example, "X:") or a directory on another volume (for example, "Y:\MountX"). The string must end with a trailing backslash ('').
>
> `[in] lpszVolumeName`
>
> A volume GUID path for the volume. This string must be of the form "\?\Volume{GUID}" where GUID is a GUID that identifies the volume. The "\?" turns off path parsing and is ignored as part of the path, as discussed in Naming a Volume.

- winapi bindings: https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/winbase/fn.SetVolumeMountPointW.html

> **Function winapi::um::winbase::SetVolumeMountPointW**
>
> ```
> pub unsafe extern "system" fn SetVolumeMountPointW(
>     lpszVolumeMountPoint: LPCWSTR, 
>     lpszVolumeName: LPCWSTR
> ) -> BOOL
> ```

- windows-rs bindings: https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Storage/FileSystem/fn.SetVolumeMountPointW.html

> **Function windows::Win32::Storage::FileSystem::SetVolumeMountPointW**
>
> ```
> pub unsafe fn SetVolumeMountPointW<P0, P1>(
>     lpszvolumemountpoint: P0,
>     lpszvolumename: P1
> ) -> BOOL
> where
>     P0: IntoParam<PCWSTR>,
>     P1: IntoParam<PCWSTR>,
> ```
>
> Required features: "Win32_Storage_FileSystem", "Win32_Foundation"

You probably also want to use `QueryDosDeviceW`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-querydosdevicew, https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/fileapi/fn.QueryDosDeviceW.html, https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Storage/FileSystem/fn.QueryDosDeviceW.html